# older version Grails and Apache-Ivy and Ant

Tags: grails

I am trying to install a program based on old grails-version to which I am very new.

My program has the following characteristics:

```
Grails Version is 1.1.//
  jdk version is 8 //
  ivy version is 2.0.0 //
  IntelliJ 2019.2.3 //
```

I get the following errors:

1-In build.xml compileClasspath, testClasspath and runtimeClasspath cannot compile and are red

```
<macrodef name="grails">
    <attribute name="script"/>
    <attribute name="args" default="" />
    <sequential>
        <grailsTask script="@{script}" args="@{args}" classpathref="grails.classpath">
            <compileClasspath refid="compile.classpath"/>
            <testClasspath refid="test.classpath"/>
            <runtimeClasspath refid="app.classpath"/>
        </grailsTask>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

2-In build.xml xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" cannot compile and is red

3-Ant-Build message
Unable to start Grails java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I try to switch to Grails Version =2.5.6 and Ant version = 1.7.1, but still getting errors.

Could somebody help.
I cannot go forward.
I am stuck.

Comment: "Grails Version is 1.1.// jdk version is 8" - Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mrs  Jeff Scott Brown, i will try the cases (Grails Version is 1.1.// jdk version is 7) and   (Version is 2.3.// jdk version is 8).